# Connected space minus a singleton remains connected

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

My (likely flawed) argument is that a continuous function (wrt to the subspace topology: IMPORTANT premise) from $C \setminus \{x\}$ to a discrete set (say $\{0,1\}$) is constant, if it were not then by adding x again we would find a continuous function from $C$ to  $\mathbb{N}$ wich is not constant.

My guess that MAYBE not all continuous function on $C \setminus \{x\}$ to $\{0,1\}$ could be extended to a continuous function on $C$. Is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But the statement is false! $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, but $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ isn't.

Comment: you are right. Thanks. What is the flaw in my argument though? I couldn't spot it on my own

Comment: @Averroes I don't understand your argument. What do you mean by “adding $x$ again”? If the domain of a function is $C\setminus\{x\}$ you can't just add $x$. And if you extend the function to $C$, what makes you think that the extension is continuous?

Comment: Fair points. How could we prove that a construction is impossible in this case? (not possible to find an extension)

Comment: In your example I can see that whatever value I would give to $f^*(0)$ $f^*$ being any extension of a continuous function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ with two distinct discreet values. $f^*$ would fail to be continuous wrt to the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Averroes Because if it was possible, then $\mathbb R$ would be disconnected. But it is connected.

Comment: Sure I know that I am stating the obvious (apologies). When I made the flaw argument I had a sphere in mind. So for which type of connected sets ,taking out a point make them non-connected? (again my guess is that somewhere the space must be the union of two connected sets plus a point of intersection, but that is just a guess)

Comment: I also do not see how this could hold: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638652/connected-spaces-minus-proper-subspaces-is-connected

Comment: @Averroes I don't know the answer to that question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69915/discussion-between-averroes-and-jose-carlos-santos).